Batching inserts on spring boot/JPA/Hibernate
I'm using spring boot with JPA for a Rest application.
I need to batch my inserts into my database, because I have to migrate a lot of rows from a DB to another. For this operation I'm using the following configurations:
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=1000
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts=true

Now I need to know if batching is really running, and for this I'm using
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics=true

The problem is that in no places in my VSCode environment I'm able to find statistics, it must be something like this:
11232586 nanoseconds spent preparing 4 JDBC statements;
4076610 nanoseconds spent executing 4 JDBC statements;
0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;

Does anybody know how to solve?
Thanks in advance
Max
